# Trying to start apache2 in debug mode starts the apache2 service automatically

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, python, debug

I am trying to remote debug (python via wsgi) starting the apache2 process with the following command (env variables set prior to calling this):

```
$HTTPD ${APACHE_ARGUMENTS} -X -k start
```

The problem is that the Apache service decides to kick in, which is really not desirable in debugging situation (it captures the debugger without sufficient permissions.....). This results with the following process status:

```
root      7635  0.0  0.0   4440   648 ?        S    08:30   0:00 /bin/sh /dev_machine_scripts/run_apache.bash
www-data  7638  1.0  1.2 396316 12568 ?        Sl   08:30   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -X -k start
www-data  7639  0.3  0.6 197292  6580 ?        Sl   08:30   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -X -k start
```

calling:

```
service apache2 service
```

outputs:

```
* apache2 is running
```

Yet the process was invoked by a bash file as single process.

Any clue how to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure systemd doesn't start Apache by itself. You can do that with:

```
$ service apache2 stop
```

Then start the 'debugging session'. If you want to continue daily operation:

```
$ service apache2 start
```

Comment: I am way beyond that... I have made sure that the very call to apache2 -X is starting the 2 processes